# DocFX relative path to 'src' folder

Tags: documentation-generation, docfx

There's something I'm missing in DocFX configuration - so it does not generate proper documentation.

I have a following folder structure:

```
+Documentation
 |- _site
 |- api
 |- apidoc
 |- articles
 |- images
 |- src    <-- This folder is autogenerated by `docfx init` command as a folders above
  docfx.json
  index.md
  toc.md
+packages
 |- Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.0.1
 |- ... other nuget folders
+src
 |- MyRealProject
   |- assets
   |- bin
   |- Commands
   |- obj
   |- Properties
   |- vendor      <- This folder should be excluded for documentation
   app.config
   MyRealProject.csproj
   MyRealProject.csproj.user
   Program.cs
+test
 |-MyRealProjext.XUnit
   |- bin
   |- obj
   |- Properties
   app.config
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.gitmodule
MyRealProject.sln
```

My docfx.json:

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "**/*.csproj"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/obj/**",
            "**/bin/**",
            "_site/**",
            "vendor/**"
          ],
          "src": "../src"
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api"
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**.yml",
          "api/index.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**.md",
          "articles/**/toc.yml",
          "toc.yml",
          "*.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "apidoc/**.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
     ],
     "dest": "_site",
     "globalMetadataFiles": [],
     "fileMetadataFiles": [],
    "template": [
      "default"
     ],
    "postProcessors": [],
    "noLangKeyword": false
  }
}
```

running the command `docfx build` generate documentation without erros but when navigating to `http://locahost:8080` open directory listing instead the `index.html` from `_site` folder. I mean I see an web page with just folders list: 
    api/
    apidoc/
    articles/
    images/
    _site/
    etc..
and even If I enter into the `_site` folder and click on `index.html` - it does open the docfx generated page but clicking on 'Api documentation' on the top shows text: `TODO: Add .NET projects to the src folder and run docfx to generate REAL API Documentation!`

- What should I reconfigure in docfx.json so it would correctly read /src folder and not /Documentation/src folder ?
- Is this a correct way to exclude `vendor/` folder from inside `src/` folder ?

Answer (score 5):

My mistake. Everything is working as normal.

I was using the code download from [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx) and compiled locally. The issue was not in configuration file (this working as expected) but in template generation. For some reason the code from [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx) coming without even 'default' template. So even after I execute the first step: `docfx.exe metadata` -> metadata generated but it never converted to Table Of Context (TOC) because template engine was missing. So running `docfx.exe build` + `serve` show the empty site. There's a separate [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/tree/dev/src/docfx.website.themes/default) page for 'default' template

Comment: How is this useful? Short of picking off files, there is no way to download it independently.